# MPI_Irecv doesn't receive message sent after loop

Tags: c++, mpi

I've been doing a parallel implementation of the dining philosophers problem and have come to a problem which I cannot solve. Basically, I have a for loop in which a process checks for any new messages and then sleeps for half a second (it repeats this a random number of times). After that part it tries to gather all the needed forks in order to start the "eating" part of the programm.

The problem is that for some reason, if I send a MPI message from inside the for loop, the target process recieves it normally, but if I send a message after the loop, it doesn't. Let me show how that looks in code, hopefully it will make things a bit more clear:

```
for (int i = 0; i < think; i++) {
        Sleep(500);

        // Recieve messages
        MPI_Irecv(&rcv, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, NEED_FORK, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
        MPI_Test(&req, &flag, &status);

        if(flag != 0) {
            // Do stuff
        }
        MPI_Send(&myid, 1, MPI_INT, target, NEED_FORK, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // He recieves this
    }
MPI_Send(&myid, 1, MPI_INT, target, NEED_FORK, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // He doesn't recieve this
```

The problem is that, for some reason, the targert process doesn't recieve any message sent after the for loop finished, while it recieves any message sent before or during the loop. I really have no idea what to do to make this work and would greatly appreciate any help...

Comment: I still haven't found the answer, but I'm pretty sure that there's something wrong with the way I use the MPI_Test function. For some reason, it doesn't seem to go well with the Sleep function...

Comment: To clarify:  Inside the loop is one MPI_Irecv and one MPI_Send.  Every iteration of the loop will have a 1:1 match between the MPI_Send/MPI_Irecv.  However, the MPI_Send after the loop does not have a matching MPI_Irecv.  Where is the matching MPI_[I]recv call for the MPI_Send after the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer on similar question. Even code looks similar.
[Infinite loop using MPI_Irecv and MPI_Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095514/infinite-loop-using-mpi-irecv-and-mpi-test/16589899#16589899)

Please look closely on calling MPI_Test and MPI_Irecv inside loop.